# Is using HMAC to transmit a password OK?

Tags: security, hmac

I'm writing a small webapp and I don't want to transmit login passwords as cleartext. As I don't have SSL available I've written a one-time challenge system which sends a random string with the login form which is then used to hash the password using HMAC-SHA256 on the client-side. I use the random challenge string as the message and the user's password as the secret key for HMAC.

I know that self-made solutions are generally a bad idea, so I wanted to ask if I'm making a mistake here.

Comment: This might be a better question for http://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is an acceptable solution.

The purpose of a HMAC is to verify data integrity and authenticity. So you can use it to verify that the information has not changed and you can use it to verify that the user has the secret key (in your case, the password).

What it cannot do is some of the other things that SSL can do, like protect from eaves-dropping by encrypting the channel and verifying the identity of the server for the end user.

Eavesdropping: There would be nothing stopping a man-in-the-middle (MITM) from watching this transaction, intercepting the return response (the HMAC digest) and sending it on as his own request (even stopping the response from the other user).

Verifying the ID of the server: One of the most important parts you are missing here is protecting your users from being duped by a phisher. With a valid SSL cert, your users have no way of verifying if the site is your or an impostor. You are trying to protect yourself by verifying the authenticity of the end-user, which is great, but you are forgetting to protect the end user.

I'd be curious to know why you don't have SSL available. I hear this a lot and find that the usual reason is becuase someone doesn't want to pony up the $50 for the cert. But the cert is worth it and in an environment where security is important there really should not be any technical reason why SSL would not be available.

Comment: Well, I know I can't replace SSL with that and I didn't intend to do so. My question is simply if I use HMAC the correct way. For example my first version used the user's password as the message and the challenge string as the key (because I thought the _message_ I want to send to the server is the user's password). But then I noticed that the challenge string is not exactly a secret, so I switched it. Most similar solutions I came across just write `HMAC(password, challenge)` and I was unsure which should be message and which key.

Comment: As for SSL, my server has only one IP and this one is already in SSL use for another site. As of now I'm not aware of any good solution for using certificates per domain and not IP. SNI would be nice, but it's not working with IE/XP, which is still very common. UC certificates would be the only solution I know, but those cost a lot more than $50 and even that is not ideal.

Comment: In my experience, having a hosting provider add an IP address is a trivial matter. My dedicated server came with 5, my VPS came with 1 and adding additional IPs was like $1-2/month.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will need some way of linking the random string sent by the server with the client it has been sent to, otherwise an attacker could simply send the hashed password and the random string back to the server to gain access.

However, if you store the random string in some sort of server session, you then open up session spoofing as a possible attack vector.

Your solution is better than sending the password in plain text then, as an attacker will not be able to discover the user's password, but they could still pose as the user.